# Reading from text file error : Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++

I have a (10*5) matrix and two variable values typed in a text file. Matrix elements are tab separated. For example:

I want to read the matrix and two other variable values from the text file and printout.

I have to use `valarray` for matrix.

I tried in following way, but it shows "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Any suggestions about correcting my code would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

using namespace std;
using matrix = valarray<valarray<double> >;

int main()
{
    matrix table{std::valarray<double>{0.0, 10}, 10}; //updated
    //matrix table;
    double a;
    int b;

    fstream inFile;
    inFile.open("tablenew1.txt", fstream::in);
    if (inFile.is_open()) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
                inFile >> table[i][j];
            }
        }
        inFile >> a;
        inFile >> b;
        inFile.close();
    }

    //printout

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
            std::cout << std::fixed;
            std::cout << std::setprecision(4);
            cout << table[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << a << '\n';
    cout << b << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

**Update**

The updated code shows the following error:
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: `std::valarray` is not a grow-on-demand data structure. You need to set a specific size for it, then fill it with data. Also please don't post images of text, post text instead.

Comment: Your `table` has size 0x0, and it can store at most 0 elements. You need to initialize it to have 10x10 elements: `matrix table{std::valarray<double>{0.0, 10}, 10};`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, replacing ```matrix table;``` with ```matrix table{std::valarray<double>{0.0, 10}, 10};``` is giving this error:  free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped). Any suggestion please?

Comment: First suggestion: Do not use `i` and `j` as indices. Please use `row` and `column`. That makes the code much more readable!

Comment: just realized that valarray constructor takes `value, count` (not `count, value`), uh, thats nasty

Comment: you can still edit your question with the updated code. The code as posted now can get the question closed as typo, but a `free: invalid pointer` is another issue

Comment: You need to change to `matrix table(std::valarray<double>(10), 10);`

Comment: @binhgreat, it also works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
matrix table{std::valarray<double>{0.0, 10}, 10};
```

into

```
matrix table(std::valarray<double>(0.0, 10), 10);
```

to get the correct constructor.

You now get one of the other constructors (possibly the `initializer_list` or `indirect_array` ctor I think).

Comment: It worked! Thank you. Can you explain me what does ```{0.0, 10}``` mean? I guess 10 is the column and row size, but could not understand what is ```0.0 ``` for?

Comment: @sede You're welcome! For the inner `valarray`, `0.0` is the value and `10` is the number of elements.
For the outer `valarray`, `valarray<double>(0.0, 10)` is the value and `10` is the number of elements.

Comment: @sede I made an example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/v1Wqba) to make it easier to see.

Comment: Ted, can i ask you one more question? If the matrix elements have different values, then what should be the syntax? ```0.0``` gives all values 0.

Comment: @sede You've initialized it with `0.0` so if reading the file doesn't change those values, then I guess that the file also contains all zeroes - or that reading the file fails. Check all the `inFile >> ...` lines. Do `if(not (inFile >> variable)) std::cout << "reading failed\n";`